# django-static-precompiler throwing error with no message

Tags: django, sass, django-static-precompiler

I'm trying to use django-static-precompiler to compile scss but I'm getting an error StaticCompilationError that says `No exception message supplied` The version for django-static-precompiler is 2.0 and sass is installed and is the latest version (1.32.6). I have the precompiler configured to point to node modules in my settings.py.

```
STATIC_PRECOMPILER_COMPILERS = (
    ('static_precompiler.compilers.SCSS', {
        "executable": "node_modules/.bin/sass"
    }),
)
```

Here is a snippet from the template it's used in: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "/css/style.scss"|compile %}" />`

The error message is not very helpful. Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-static-precompiler does not work with Dart Sass. You could either use ruby-sass which is deprecated or use a different precompiler.